# Center image login on xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I try to use an image for the login on my ios app. I have created this image with Sketch and upload on my xcode project. I have disabled : Use auto-layout And Use size class because when it's enable my texfiled don't match with the image.
But with this settings for iphone 5 it's ok, but on iphone 6 or heigher this is the result : 
[image: Image iphone 6 result]

And the correct result on iphone 5 : 
[image: Correct result]

So how can I fixe this problem in Xcode using image for the background

Comment: You have to add constraints to your `UIImageView`. Please read this:  [Understanding Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/)

Comment: If I add constraints ( when I enable size class ), the texfiled aren't at the good place ...

Comment: Firstly you should select any, any size class after that you try to add constrains on every ui elements.

Comment: So I need to use Size Class or not ( Enable or disable ? )

Answer (score 0):

you don't need size classes in this case, but you do need to enable and use AutoLayout. You can read more here - [Understanding AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/).

Comment: if I use Auto Layout, my textfield do not match with username and password field on the image [See the screen](http://imgur.com/ezXTFeQ)